# How to make a new column in a data.frame so that column counts the number of different row in that data.frame?

Tags: r

I have a huge data.frame like this.

First, how can I add a new column "date1" into this data.frame so that column counts the number of the UNIQUE different day in this data.frame then arranged in ascending order in that newly created column.

Second, how can I add another column "date2" into this data.frame so that column counts total different id in a day?

```
    year  month day id
    2011    1   5   31
    2011    1   14  22
    2011    2   6   28
    2011    2   17  41
    2011    3   9   55
    2011    1   5   34
    2011    1   14  25
    2011    2   6   36
    2011    2   17  11
    2011    3   12  10
```

The result I expect looks like this. Please help!

```
    year month day  id date1 date2
    2011    1   5   31  1     2
    2011    1   14  22  2     2
    2011    2   6   28  3     2
    2011    2   17  41  4     2
    2011    3   9   55  5     1
    2011    1   5   34  1     2
    2011    1   14  25  2     2
    2011    2   6   36  3     2
    2011    2   17  11  4     2
    2011    3   12  10  6     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this more compactly in `tidyverse` by getting the `group_indices` of 'year', 'month', 'day' in the `group_by` and then create the 'date2' as the number of distinct elements of 'id' (`n_distinct`)

```
librarytidyverse)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(date1 = group_indices(., year, month, day)) %>% 
     mutate(date2 = n_distinct(id))
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   date1 [6]
#    year month   day    id date1 date2
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1  2011     1     5    31     1     2
# 2  2011     1    14    22     2     2
# 3  2011     2     6    28     3     2
# 4  2011     2    17    41     4     2
# 5  2011     3     9    55     5     1
# 6  2011     1     5    34     1     2
# 7  2011     1    14    25     2     2
# 8  2011     2     6    36     3     2
# 9  2011     2    17    11     4     2
#10  2011     3    12    10     6     1
```

---

Or another compact option with `data.table` (using the same logic)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, date1 := .GRP, .(year, month, day)][, date2 := uniqueN(id), date1][]
#     year month day id date1 date2
# 1: 2011     1   5 31     1     2
# 2: 2011     1  14 22     2     2
# 3: 2011     2   6 28     3     2
# 4: 2011     2  17 41     4     2
# 5: 2011     3   9 55     5     1
# 6: 2011     1   5 34     1     2
# 7: 2011     1  14 25     2     2
# 8: 2011     2   6 36     3     2
# 9: 2011     2  17 11     4     2
#10: 2011     3  12 10     6     1
```

---

Or this can be done with `interaction` and `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$date1 <- with(df1, as.integer(interaction(year, month, day, 
         drop = TRUE, lex.order = TRUE)))
df1$date2 <- with(df1, ave(id, date1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L), month = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), day = c(5L, 14L, 6L, 17L, 9L, 5L, 14L, 6L, 17L, 
12L), id = c(31L, 22L, 28L, 41L, 55L, 34L, 25L, 36L, 11L, 10L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can first combine `year`, `month` and `day` into one column using `unite` and give a unique number to each group of that combination, then `group_by` same combination and count the unique `id` for each combination using `n_distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unite(date, year, month, day, sep = "-", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(date1 = as.integer(factor(date,level = unique(date)))) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(date2 = n_distinct(id)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-date)


#    year month   day    id date1 date2
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1  2011     1     5    31     1     2
# 2  2011     1    14    22     2     2
# 3  2011     2     6    28     3     2
# 4  2011     2    17    41     4     2
# 5  2011     3     9    55     5     1
# 6  2011     1     5    34     1     2
# 7  2011     1    14    25     2     2
# 8  2011     2     6    36     3     2
# 9  2011     2    17    11     4     2
#10  2011     3    12    10     6     1
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah, I have tried but the data1 column result is not as what I am expected. I have 3 year data, the final day of the data should be the largest number in the new column but it isn't. It's another day in the data. There are mistakes here and there like that. Date2 is ok.